# How to find out the amount of time a button is being touched in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, timer

My requirement is to change a button color  based on the time it is being pressed. for ex,button should be in red color if it is being touched for one sec, green for two secs, etc. How do i do it?

I could find out the amount of time after user takes his hand out, but I want it to be done when it is being pressed?. What is the efficient way to do it?.

Answer (score 0):

U can start an NSTimer which fires every second , which is started when UIButton `UIControlEventTouchDown` control event is generated. And stop the timer when `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` or `UIControlEventTouchUpOutside` or `UIControlEventTouchCancel` event is generated. In between u can do the changes.

Comment: I tried this method already. The problem here is, if the touch event is swift(less than 1 sec), invalidating the timer would lead to crash.I am looking for more efficient solution. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Actually i reduced the timer's schedule time. say 0.1s. It works but inefficient,so many calls!.

Comment: Actually I tried this method. Starting the timer when the button is touched down. And invalidating when touched up inside. Even if it is less than 1 sec, it is not getting crashed.

Comment: you tried to invalidate a timer even before it is created and it is not crashed?.apple documentation says invalidate method, is the only way to remove a timer from an NSRunLoop object. The NSRunLoop object removes and releases the timer, either just before the invalidate method returns or at some later point. So there is chance that it might crash.we can't rely on it.